# How to execute an .sh file

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to install a driver using a shell file:

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/WIFI_DRIVER$ ls
android_ref_codes_JB_4.2  btcoex    install.sh        WiFi_Direct_User_Interface
android_ref_codes_KK_4.4  document  readme.txt        wireless_tools
android_ref_codes_L_5.0   driver    ReleaseNotes.pdf  wpa_supplicant_hostapd
```

Then:

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/WIFI_DRIVER$ install.sh
install.sh: command not found
```

Fair enough:

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/WIFI_DRIVER$ ./install.sh
bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied
```

How about this:

```
yoav@yoav-System:~/Documents/WIFI_DRIVER$ sudo ./install.sh
sudo: ./install.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to make the shell script executable?

Comment: Make the install.sh executable first: `sudo chmod +x install.sh` and try again: `./install.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may turn out that the script does not have executable permission.

1.Make the script executable using

```
sudo chmod +x install.sh
```

2.Run the script using

```
./install.sh
```

If you get an error indicating `bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied'` , run the command with elevated privileges

```
sudo ./install.sh
```